# Will Questions about the new Compute module and it's IO Board be on-topic?

Tags: discussion, on-off-topic

So RaspberryPiFoundation realeased the new [Compute Module](http://www.raspberrypi.org/raspberry-pi-compute-module-new-product/), which I'm really excited about.

It's obviously a Raspberry Pi device; does that mean questions about it will be on-topic here?

I ask because I'm sure it will have it's own quirks, and different problems than the original Pi's because of the nature of the device.

Alternatively, will it just have it's own tag in the tag wiki?

Thanks!

evamvid

Comment: As far as I understand the compute module, it is, in essence, just a Raspberry Pi with a different configuration. It will have a different way of interfacing with the outside world, but its heart is still a Pi, and as such, many of the questions regarding it, at least on the software side, will have the same answers as for the original two models. That said, I might just be misunderstanding what the compute module is.

Answer (score 7):

Yes to both questions.

Questions about the Compute Module ([under the same scope of what is already defined in the help centre](https://raspberrypi.stackexchange.com/help/on-topic)) will be on topic here.

And I'm sure a tag will arise as questions are asked.